Converting table names to a slave using the "master slave" principle
I am using the "master slave" principle.
I have:
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class AlertMessage extends BasicEntityAuto {

    private String nickname;
    private AlertType alertType;
    ...
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporary(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date CreatedDate;
}

there are dependencies in the pom:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.Beta1</version>
</dependency>


in the property:
server.port=8108

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy

spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.master.jdbcurl=jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3309/test
spring.datasource.master.username=root
spring.datasource.master.password=root
spring.datasource.master.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.slave1.jdbcurl=jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3310/test
spring.datasource.slave1.username=root
spring.datasource.slave1.password=root
spring.datasource.slave1.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver


Docker:
services:
  master:
    restart: always
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb_master
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./master-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./master-conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
    ports:
      - "3309:3306"
    command: >
      --server-id=1 
      --log-bin=mysql-bin 
      --binlog-do-db=test
      --binlog-format=ROW

  slave:
    restart: always
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb_slave
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./slave-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./slave-conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - ./script:/scripts
    ports:
      - "3310:3306"
    depends_on:
      - master
    command: >
      --server-id=2 
      --relay-log=relay-bin 
      --log-bin=mysql-bin 
      --skip-slave-start=0
      --scripts/script.sh`


when I start the project, I get: 
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=151) Table 'test.AlertMessage' doesn't exist
why is the AlertMessage table being searched instead of alert_message?
what settings do I lack to convert camelCase to snake_case?
specifying @Table(name = "alert_message") is not an option. also, I don't want to write my own conversion class (like: SnakeCaseNamingStrategy implements PhysicalNamingStrategy).
this problem is happening with the slave. because if I add the flag --lower_case_table_names=1 to the slave docker in command, then the tables start to be searched already like 'test.alertmessage'.
how else to specify the name specifically for the slave?
if you specify @Table(name = "alert_message") or write a custom converter, everything works, but I would like to find out an easier way.
